# How to use .toFixed() (or any alternative) on Nerdamer.solve solutions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math

I'm using `Nerdamer.solve()` to get some linear equation roots. It's working fine but I wonder if there is any way to get only the first 4 decimals of every solution.

**EquationSolver.js**

//First step, using Nerdamer to solve the equation stored in *value*

```
sol_raw = this.nerdamer.solve(value,'x');
xs = this.nerdamer(sol_raw.toString());
```

//Second step, using Function() in order to evaluate the solutions

```
 solution= Function('return ' + this.nerdamer(xs).evaluate().toString())()
```

At this point, I'm getting correct results like: 1.74343434. Since I'm rendering the results using `Katex`, I would like to know where to implement `.toFixed(4)` or any pseudo way (maybe a Nerdamer method to use n number of decimals on `.evaluate()`?).

**Note**.
The result (solution) is a string like [1.74343434, 0.434343, ...] so I could transform it into a float variable and then use `.toFixed()` but this not an easy solution because the number of roots depends on the equation's grade.

Nerdamer's documentation about evaluate: [documentation](https://nerdamer.com/functions/Expression.evaluate.html)

Comment: Looks like your result is an array of floats, correct?  Can you not map each one of the values in the array to a new array that holds the .toFixed versions of each number?  Maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: Does [Rounding of decimal numbers: Looking for an elegant way in latex table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126528) have any bearing on the problem?

Comment: @DJBurb yup this is a way but I asked for a shorter way to achieve this setting up `.evaluate()` from *Nerdaemer*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@CoronelV,

Another possible approach is to create a `toFixed` function for formatting the numbers which would take into account real and complex solutions and then calling it on your solutions. Here's a more generalized approach.

```
var toFixed = function(value, n) {
    var img = Number(nerdamer.imagpart(value).text()).toFixed(n);
    var real = Number(nerdamer.realpart(value).text()).toFixed(n);

    // Format the number assuming i denotes imaginary in your case
    var formatted = '';

    if(real !== '0.0000') {
        formatted += real;
    }

    if(img !== '0.0000') {
        // Put the plus sign betweent the real and imaginary
        if(img.charAt(0) !== '-' && formatted) {
            formatted += '+';
        }
        // Assuming you're using i and not j for instance
        formatted += img+'i';
    }

    return formatted;
};
```

So in your case this would be become something like:

```
sol_raw = this.nerdamer.solve(value,'x');
xs = this.nerdamer(sol_raw.toString()).each(function(solution) {
    roundedSolutions.push(toFixed(solution, 4));
});

this.setState({
            solution: roundedSolution.join(''),
            equation:value})
```

This would possibly eliminate the need for your try catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Since the solution is rendered using [KaTeX](https://katex.org/), it's possible rounding the solution via Latex's package, but its even simplest taking the suggestion of @Dj Burb.

Here is my approach:

```
    try {
        sol_raw = this.nerdamer.solve(value,'x');
        xs = this.nerdamer(sol_raw.toString());

        Function('return '+ this.nerdamer(xs).evaluate().toString())().forEach(element => {
            roundedSolution.push(element.toFixed(4))    });
    
    } catch (e) {
    }

    this.setState({
                solution: roundedSolution.join(''),
                equation:value})
```

The use of `try catch` is imperative because while writing the equation, `solution.toFixed()` returns an error.