# how to truncate output values in Nerdamer

Tags: javascript

I am using nerdamer.solve to solve roots but the roots are long and not truncated. I wanted to get truncated values upto 4 decimal places. How can I achieve this?
I am using the following code to solve and display output in html:

```
var r = nerdamer.solve(`1 - ${a} * x^(${p}) + ${b}`, 'x');
document.getElementById("polesAns").innerHTML= r.toString();
```

The folllowing is output:

```
[(138655807/135201312)*i+49385501/48155102,(-138655807/135201312)*i+49385501/48155102,(58886197/57419096)*i-49385501/48155102,(-58886197/57419096)*i-49385501/48155102,-560373381/386371730,172668482/119053157,(145619303/100403024)*i-5753750945848186/10000000000000000000000000000000,(-560373381/386371730)*i-5753750945848186/10000000000000000000000000000000]
```

There is no division performed also.

I tried the solution posted here:
[How to use .toFixed() (or any alternative) on Nerdamer.solve solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67338982/how-to-use-tofixed-or-any-alternative-on-nerdamer-solve-solutions)

But how can I do this with my code? I tried the following:

```
    var value = `1 - ${a} * x^(${p}) + ${b}`;
 
 var toFixed = function(value, n) {
var img = Number(nerdamer.imagpart(value).text()).toFixed(n);
var real = Number(nerdamer.realpart(value).text()).toFixed(n);

// Format the number assuming i denotes imaginary in your case
var formatted = '';

if(real !== '0.0000') {
    formatted += real;
}

if(img !== '0.0000') {
    // Put the plus sign betweent the real and imaginary
    if(img.charAt(0) !== '-' && formatted) {
        formatted += '+';
    }
    // Assuming you're using i and not j for instance
    formatted += img+'i';
}

return formatted;
 };
 
 sol_raw = this.nerdamer.solve(value,'s');
 xs = this.nerdamer(sol_raw.toString()).each(function(solution) {
 roundedSolutions.push(toFixed(solution, 4));
    });

this.setState({
        solution: roundedSolution.join(''),
        equation:value})
     
  document.getElementById("polesAns").value = solution.toString();
```

I don't understand the this.setState() part , should i declare sol_raw and xs as var?

Also the substitution of variable is used in the my above root equation from advice here [javascript Solving equation with subsitution of variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70907470/javascript-solving-equation-with-subsitution-of-variable-value)

thank you

Comment: setState is a react thing. are you using react

Comment: i searched for setState after it was not working then i had added the followings:<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>  
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script> but still not working